# Does an installation of Microsoft Office need to be available to access Excel workbooks via the Jet driver?

Tags: oledb

I'd like to know if Jet/OLEDB access to Excel works with the driver alone.

Answer (score 0):

It does, as long as Jet is installed Office is not needed